# Protractor can't find element by binding

Tags: protractor

I'm trying to find a element by binding, the problem is that the the element is an toast.

I'm using:

```
element(by.css('.btn-primary3')).click()
```

To simulate the click. As a result the toast does appear in the browser during the test.

Then I'm trying to store the element in a variable and test if the text value of the toast is equal to the expected value.

```
var toast = element(by.binding('toast.toast.title'));
expect(toast.getText()).toEqual('Inloggen mislukt');
```

But here the error pops up.

```
Failed: No element found using locator: by.binding("toast.toast.tile")
```

When I check the toast element in the the Chrome dev tools it shows up like this,

```
<div data-ng-repeat="toast in activeToasts">
    <span data-ng-bind="toast.toast.title" class="ng-binding"> Inloggen mislukt</span>
</div>
```

I think the problem comes from the fact that that the span containing the binding doesn't exist on the dom when the page is loaded. It gets created when the button is clicked.

Comment: Try tool called `Elementor` it rlly helps with AngularJs application and it allows you to find locators.
Is it generated as a selectlist in browser ? Need that to provide valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the case, [wait for the presence of the element](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.presenceOf) after clicking the button:

```
element(by.css('.btn-primary3')).click();
var toast = element(by.binding('toast.toast.title'));

browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(toast), 5000);
expect(toast.getText()).toEqual('Inloggen mislukt');
```

Comment: I am getting `EC is not defined` !!

Comment: @AnkurShah ah yeah, it is defined as `var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions`.

Answer (score 0):

May you should try:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="toast in activeToasts">
    <span data-ng-bind="toast.toast.title" class="ng-binding"> Inloggen mislukt</span>
</div>
```